Resolve merge conflicts due to file split
I have been working on a feature branch. On master there was a refactoring which has split one file into several. In my feature branch there are changes to that big file. When trying to merge master into my feature branch I get a lot of merge conflicts. The one for the big file is just a "you've changed stuff, on the other end it was deleted" and doesn't help me to adapt my changes to the new split file situation. Unfortunately there have been other changes before and after the split as well. Is there some way that git merge can help me here?

I wonder if you could try splitting it into 3 merges: First merge the last commit from master before the commit that splits the file. (Resolve conflicts.) Now merge just the commit that splits the file. (Resolve conflicts.) Now merge in master (Resolve conflicts one last time.) It isn't perfect and I'm not sure if it will even help that much, but if it does  it's still O(1) operations.

@TTT: If the commit with the split would only contain the split, then this would indeed be a viable approach. I think that there are many changes together in that change.
